# show that if $G/K, G/N$ are solvable then $G/(K \cap N)$ is also solvable

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group and let $N,K \lhd G$ be her normal subgroups. It is given that $G/N$ and $G/K$ are solvable.

I need to prove that $G/(K \cap N)$ is also solvable.

I thought about proving somehow that $(G/K) \times (G/N) \cong (G/(K \cap N))$, using the theorem which says that: if $H,M \lhd G$ and $HM = G$ and $H \cap M = {e}$, then $G \cong H \times M$

Then it will follow, since I already proved once that if $H,M$ are solvable, then $H \times M$ is also solvable.

However, I didn't manage to prove the isomorphism part.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: construct an *injective* homomorphism from $G/(K \cap N)$ to $G/K \times G/N$ and use that products and subgroups of solvable groups are again solvable.

Comment: I think the homomorphism: $g(K \cap N) \mapsto (gK, gN)$ will work. Right?

Comment: Yes, excellent, but you still need to prove that it is well-defined (so independent of the coset representative), homomorphic and injective. Then you are good to go!

Comment: Yes I got it, thanks again

Comment: Could you maybe write the part about showing it is well defined?

Comment: Yes. The definition of your map above might depend on the choice of the coset representative $g$. So if $g(K \cap N)=h(K \cap N)$, then you need to show that indeed $(gK,gN)=(hK,hN)$. Now, $g(K \cap N)=h(K \cap N)$, implies $h^{-1}g \in K \cap N$, hence $h^{-1}g \in K$, equivalent to $gK=hK$ and similarly, $gN=hN$.

Comment: Okay, now everything is clear. Much obliged